# Sparx Enterprise Architect diagram with endpoints

Tags: diagram, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to structure a big diagram by building smaller diagrams and then connect them in the big picture. The problem i got now is that i can't figure out how to add connectors/endpoint to the diagram frame so that i can follow the arrows between the different diagrams.

Would be grateful for some help figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. A diagram is not an UML object per se. It's a rendering of a number of elements from the model. So you can not connect anything from inside a diagram frame to the outside.

What I did in similar circumstances was that I placed the element in question aside the frame (probably surrounded by a boundary and some explanatory text) from where I show the connectors going somewhere else in that diagram.

Answer (score 0):

The "diagram frame" element type, which you can create by dragging a diagram from the element browser onto another diagram in the main view, is an EA-specific construct that has no basis in UML. Even within EA, they are strange beasts which fall somewhere between proper elements, which are shown in the project browser and can be dragged into any number of diagrams, and "pure" diagram objects which aren't shown in the project browser (such as Notes).

While you can draw connectors from one diagram frame to another in the normal ways, there is no way to create a connector going from an element within one frame, out of the frame's bounds and into another frame. This is because the elements within the frame are not actually present in the diagram which contains the frame; the frame is simply an image of the diagram it refers to.